# Refactoring form code in php

Tags: php, refactoring

I get three values from a form (thread_title, thread_content and thread_tags):

This is the code to check their lengths:

```
$errors = array();

$thread_title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'thread_title');
$thread_content = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'thread_content');
$thread_tags = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'thread_tags');


if (strlen($thread_title) < 20 )
{
    $errors['thread_title'] = 'Title is too short, minimum is 20 characters.';    
}

if (strlen($thread_content) < 30 )
{
    $errors['thread_content'] = 'Content is too short, minimum is 30 characters.';
}

if (strlen($thread_tags) < 3)
{
    $errors['thread_tags'] = 'Tags must be atleast 3 characters.';
}
```

I repeat this in the reply.php file:

```
if (strlen($reply_content) < 20)
{
    $errors['reply_content'] = 'Reply must be atleast 20 characters.';
}
```

.etc

If the errors array is empty I then clean the data and submit it to the database. How can this code be made cleaner, refactored?

I know I can use something like PEAR QUICK_FORM (2.0?), however that is still in alpha and the error messages appear as a JS popup in that and not next to the required field.

Comment: You could post this on [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and probably get some good feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

github is a source of lot of really good code. I did a quick search for [form validation](https://github.com/search?type=Everything&language=php&q=form+validation&repo=&langOverride=&x=9&y=26&start_value=1). For example:

- https://github.com/bretticus/PHP-5.3-Form-Validator looks okay?

Furthermore I believe if you want to refactor your code, you should practice TDD(unit testing).

Comment: Ubuntu karmic koala only comes with 5.2?

Comment: Why are you running an old version of Ubuntu. The new version is waaaaaaaaaaay better. You should do an update. Also the new PHP is going to be a lot faster without even changing any of your code. Also when coding in PHP5.3 you can create a lot cleaner code. My advice is to update!!

Comment: My laptop is rubbish and old, I'm doing it now but It requires 1.4GBs.

Comment: p.s: you could also try and install [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html) ;). It is portable and you don't require update although I think you really should. Linux/Ubuntu has gotten a lot better since.

Comment: p.s: there also is http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html, but then you are going to need to use Codeigniter as your framework. Although Codeigniter is pretty good!

Comment: very good :P. You will also notice a speed bump without even modifying any code. Now you can also right a lot cleaner code. PHP5.3 has a lot of cool features :P.